# Node.js/Express.js App Only Works on Port 3000

Tags: javascript, node.js, configuration, express, port

I have a Node.js/Express.js app running on my server that only works on port 3000 and I'm trying to figure out why. Here's what I've found:

- Without specifying a port (`app.listen()`), the app runs but the web page does not load.
- On port 3001 (`app.listen(3001)`) or any other port that is not in use, the app runs but the web page does not load.
- On port 2999, the app throws an error because something else is using that port.
- On port 3000, the app runs and the web page loads fine.

I know that Express apps default to port 3000. But strangely, my app only runs when I explicitly make it run on port 3000 (`app.listen(3000)`).

I found this on line 220 of `/usr/bin/express`:

```
app.set(\'port\', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

Which is doing as previously stated: setting the port to what is specified or to 3000 if nothing is specified.

How could I make my app work on a different port such as 8080 or 3001?

Thanks!

**Edit: Code Sample (Very Simple Node/Express App)**

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world'); 
});

// Only works on 3000 regardless of what I set environment port to or how I set [value] in app.set('port', [value]).
app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: 1) A `port` is required by [`.listen()`](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_server_listen_port_hostname_backlog_callback), so you shouldn't try going without. 2) Are you getting any errors when running the application? Or does it just seem inaccessible from a browser? 3) Are you trying to access the website on the same machine with `localhost:3000`, `localhost:3001`, etc.? If you're using two machines, one client and one server, you'll need to add exceptions to the firewall on the server to allow Node to receive requests from the client.

Comment: How are you launching the app?

Comment: Any chance you can put a scrubbed/sanitized version up in a gist?

Comment: @Jonathan Good to know about `.listen()`. Above when I say, "the app runs", this is the same as you saying, "no errors when running the application". When I say, "web page does not load", this is the same as you saying, "inaccessible from a browser". All access from the same machine (my server). Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @deitch I'm using `$ supervisor app.js` or `$ PORT=[PORT] node app.js` when I want to set the environment port variable. I'll put up a code sample.

Comment: Ah, you're still explicitly putting `3000` in your code...let me clean your code for you and look for it in my answer.

Comment: @BenjaminMartin If you're getting an error of something else using that port, then maybe you're not properly stopping your `node` instances. do a `ps -ax| grep node` and make sure no node processes are already binding to the port you're trying to use

Comment: The principles everyone is laying out are correct. Any chance we can get a gist or cut/paste of the very basic that doesn't work?

Comment: Just specify it in your launch script `PORT=3001 DEBUG=myapp:* npm start`

Answer (score 138, accepted):

The following works if you have something like this in your app.js:

```
http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'),
  function(){
    console.log("Express server listening on port " + app.get('port'));
});
```

Either explicitly hardcode your code to use the port you want, like:

```
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
```

This code means set your port to the environment variable `PORT` or if that is `undefined` then set it to the literal `3000`.

Or, use your environment to set the port. Setting it via the environment is used to help delineate between `PRODUCTION` and `DEVELOPMENT` and also a lot of Platforms as a Service use the environment to set the port according to their specs as well as internal Express configs. The following sets an environment key=value pair and then launches your app.

```
$ PORT=8080 node app.js
```

In reference to your code example, you want something like this:

```
var express = require("express");
var app = express();

// sets port 8080 to default or unless otherwise specified in the environment
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 8080);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.send('hello world');
});

// Only works on 3000 regardless of what I set environment port to or how I set
// [value] in app.set('port', [value]).
// app.listen(3000);
app.listen(app.get('port'));
```

Comment: This is really weird. I have done the following: 1. Put the `app.set()` code inside my app and changed 3000 to 8080. Still only works on `app.listen(3000)`. 2. Change the environment port variable to 8080 when running the node app. Still only works on `app.listen(3000)`. 3. Gone to /usr/bin/express (line 220) and changed 3000 to 8080. Still only works on `app.listen(3000)`. Thank you for the informative post though. Is there something I need to restart? Express can't be restarted from what I can tell and restarting the Node app happens every time I use `node app.js.`

Comment: @BenjaminMartin Express is just a module like any other module, so just a simple `node app.js` will start it (I personally use `nodemon` when developing and testing. What you might be thinking of is the `express` command-line executable that is a helper process that builds out your skeleton file structure. Can you post a gist of your code?

Comment: gotcha. I usually only use `nodemon` in conjunction with `nohup` to keep my app running indefinitely. I'm not using the CL executable version of `express` so it must be restarting every time I restart my `node` app. See my original post for an edit with code. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminMartin check the bottom of my answer and run that code. That should work just fine. I just tested it on my machine.

Comment: This is another useful way to change the port but it still only works when the port is 3000. I'm starting to wonder if there's something on my server that only allows content to be served on certain ports. I have no idea where this configuration would be located though. Could this be an issue? FYI I'm running Ubuntu 10.04.

Comment: @BenjaminMartin make sure that PORT=3000 is not set(or overwrite it to PORT=8080), make sure no other `node` processes are going on that port and make sure you're not explicitly pointing it to there. Make sure you directly copy my code verbatim and test. If that doesn't work then something weird is going on (but not that weird or it wouldn't work at all)

Comment: I have made sure of all those things. I now realize there may be a miscommunication: When I set the port to 8080 as per any of the methods above, the app works when I browse to http://website.com:8080. But it only works on 3000 without specifying the port (http://website.com). Because http is run on port 80, it seems there's something on my server telling port 80 to forward traffic to port 3000 (or vice versa). I tried the second solution down here to no avail: [link](bit.ly/1ehMZpO).

Comment: Ultimately I want to run multiple node apps on my server. I think I will need to use Nginx rather than fiddle around with getting different ports to work.

Comment: @BenjaminMartin well, if you're trying your website.com:8080, then it will go out to the internet and use the internet IP which will then route through your router. If your router does a port forward, like 8080 to 3000, then it won't work, yet your intranet ip:8080 would work just fine.

Comment: Using express js and Vs Code as a debugger, had to change the port at line 28, worked!!

Comment: `http.createServer` is not needed I think: `http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port')..`. It does the same as `express`.

Comment: on linux, a port may be inaccessible because of local firewall settings (e.g. firewalld, iptables) as well as selinux... may be the installation of node did create at the same time the firewall and selinux rules for port 3000 but no other

Answer (score 37):

In `bin/www`, there is a line:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
```

Try to modify it.

Comment: I tried setting the port in app.js but this line was overriding. This is the correct place to change the port.

Answer (score 16):

Try this

```
$ PORT=8080 node app.js
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer - this only works if I have app.listen(3000) set inside app.js. In other words, setting the port when I run the app as you have done doesn't seem to override app.listen().

Comment: Perfect. I use is with express: PORT=8000 npm start. So you can use whatever you want :D.

Answer (score 14):

[image: Refer to this link.]

Try to locate the bin>www location and try to change the port number...

Answer (score 12):

The default way to change the listening port on The Express framework is to modify the file named www in the bin folder.

There, you will find a line such as the following

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
```

Change the value 3000 to any port you wish.

This is valid for Express version 4.13.1

Answer (score 4):

Just a note for Mac OS X and Linux users:

If you want to run your Node / Express app on a port number lower than 1024, you have to run as the superuser: 
`sudo PORT=80 node app.js`

Comment: A better option to run your app on a port below 1024 is to forward a port with greater number. Using sudo to be able to access a port number lower than 1024 is generally considered bad practice.

Answer (score 4):

In the lastest version of code with express-generator (4.13.1) app.js is an exported module and the server is started in /bin/www using app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3001) in app.js will be overridden by a similar statement in bin/www.
I just changed the statement in bin/www.

Answer (score 3):

In app.js, just add...

```
process.env.PORT=2999;
```

This will isolate the PORT variable to the express application.

Answer (score 2):

Noticed this was never resolved... You likely have a firewall in front of your machine blocking those ports, or iptables is set up to prevent the use of those ports.

Try running nmap -F localhost when you run your app (install nmap if you don't have it). If it appears that you're running the app on the correct port and you can't access it via a remote browser then there is some middleware or a physical firewall that's blocking the port.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's what worked for me. Forgot to allow the port.

Answer (score 2):

The line you found just looks for the environmental variable `PORT`, if it's defined it uses it, otherwise uses the default port `3000`. You have to define this environmental variable first (no need to be root)

```
export PORT=8080
node <your-app.js>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show something you're connected on 3000

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(3000, function () {
  console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!')
})
```

I hope that will be helpful to you

Answer (score 2):

## Answer according to ***current version of express***

If you talk about the ***current version of express***, if you run ***`app.listen()`*** to start listening without specifying port, Express will chose a ***random port*** for your application, to find out about which port it is currently running on use

```
app.listen(0, () => {
    console.log(app.address().port)
}
```

should **output** the **port** of your `app`. Moreover that first parameter `0` can be totally ignored but is ***not recommended***

Answer (score 1):

I am using the `minimist` package and the node startup arguments to control the port.

`node server.js --port 4000`

or

`node server.js -p 4000`

Inside server.js, the port can be determined by

```
var argv = parseArgs(process.argv.slice(2))

const port = argv.port || argv.p || 3000;
console.log(`Listening on port ${port}...`)

//....listen(port);
```

and it defaults to 3000 if no port is passed as an argument.

You can then use listen on the `port` variable.

Comment: single hyphen `-p` didn't worked for me. But double hyphen `--p` working. Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are running from that folder of your application, where you have the package.json.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to use [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv) package and set the port on the `.env` config file without to modify the file `www` inside the folder `bin`.

Just install the package with the command:

```sh
npm install dotenv
```

require it on your application:

```
require('dotenv').config()
```

Create a .env file in the root directory of your project, and add the port in it (for example) to listen on port 5000

```
PORT=5000
```

and that's it.

More info [here](https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Nodemon my guess is the PORT 3000 is set in the nodemonConfig.
Check if that is the case.