# .listen method parameters in NodeJS

Tags: node.js

NodeJS noob checking in. I am looking at the documentation for the .listen method, which has this form:

```
server.listen(port[, hostname][, backlog][, callback])
```

And the explanation of port/hostname states:

> Begin accepting connections on the specified port and hostname. If the
>   hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to
>   any IPv4 addres

I don't fully understand the 'If the hostname is omitted, the server will accept connections directed to any IPv4 address' part. How can a server accept connections to any IP address? Is it a matter of what the server will accept rather than what it can accept that makes this seem strange to me?

Comment: BTW, the hostname can be omitted, but the port not, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18024792/1705829).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is when your current host that the server is running on has multiple IP addresses (multiple nics or multiple IP addresses for one nic).  See [multihoming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multihoming).

So, that statement means that if not hostname is provided, then any incoming connection that arrives on this particular host will be accepted regardless of which IP address the connection was targeted for.

Comment: If we are talking about a nodeJS http server, is any request considered to be a connection? Say I have http requests to this nodeJS app from some application (chrome extension in this case), how do I know what hostname to specify?

Comment: @pqx994 - "connections" in this context are any incoming TCP connections.  Every incoming http request is such a connection.

Comment: Sorry, edited the original comment and added some more. I am wondering how do you know the hostname to specify then, if you are making http requests from an external app like a chrome extension? Is the hostname generally left blank in that case?

Comment: @pqx994 - The hostname in this context is your server's hostname.  That parameter has nothing to do with where a connection is coming "from".  The usual case is to omit the hostname which is most likely what you should do.  It might be used in much more complicated deployments (think about multiple web servers on the same host).

Comment: Thanks, appreciate the explanation