# NodeJs (Express) wont listen to the IP and host in ubuntu

Tags: node.js, express

I have deployed my app to ununtu.

this is the bin/www:

```
app.set('port', 3000);
app.set('host','app.site.com');
var server = http.createServer(app);
server.listen(port,'64.143.255.122');//I put here a fake IP (deployed with the real one)
server.on('error', onError);
server.on('listening', onListening);
```

I have created a host in my PC: `64.143.255.122 app.site.com` and I open the browser in: `http://app.site.com:3000` and it does not work.

But, if I go via `lynx`, inside the server, and write  `lynx http://localhost:3000` it will work, I will get the correct page.

What might be the problem?

Thanks

Comment: did you try to listen on a port without specifying the ip? so that it listens on the localhost? and use 3000 instead of port on the sever.listen line? just to  debug?

Comment: @rmjoia - yes, exact same thing

Comment: does it throw any error? on your error event handler? You probably did find this, yet.. I think the post mentions the port binding and all ,http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008620/node-js-express-js-app-only-works-on-port-3000

Comment: What IP adress show `nslookup app.site.com`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you make iptables to allow it?

try this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3000 -j ACCEPT
```