# Express Generator ignores port setting

Tags: node.js, express

I am using the following code to set the port to 3004 in an express generator app, right above `module.exports = app;`

```
// app.js
const PORT = 3004;
app.set('port', PORT);
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`app listening on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

I tried using app.set based on this other topic: [Node.js/Express.js App Only Works on Port 3000](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18008620/node-js-express-js-app-only-works-on-port-3000)

And `app.listen` is suggested in the official docs.

They don't work together or in isolation. Running `npm start` reverts to port 3000, which crashes the app in my case since I'm using that port for another app (also express generator based).

I do not have this issue when starting from my own express app from scratch. Therefore I believe express generator is hiding the port configuration elsewhere and overriding my settings.

Does anyone know where to set the port or disable the overriding setting?

```
"express": "~4.16.0"
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When you use the generator you get a bin folder In your bin folder in www is where the port is set like so:

```
var port = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || '3000');
app.set('port', port);
```

This is where you can change it...

Comment: Aha, there it is! Thanks